# How to setup open/public DNS server in a secure way?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

For a custom application (retrieving data from embedded sensors), I need to create a fake DNS entry to redirect the requests to my servers.

I want to setup a DNS server so the users just have to change their routers DNS settings for joining.

I need to have a public DNS server.
I cannot have a client filter since some clients IP are dynamic. So it must be open to everybody.

I think dnsmasq can do the work.

**What dnsmasq settings should I take care of for making sure I'm not making a gateway for dns amplification and other attacks ?**

Comment: Nothing in your question makes sense.

Comment: Why on earth do you need to *fake* a DNS record? Why don't you register a valid domain and configure these "sensors" to use your valid and properly registered domain?

Comment: That sensors are sold for being used only with the locked vendor API. It will always call the same url, no way to change it.

This is just like http://unblock.us faking the DNS records for redirecting the requests to their proxy

Comment: Are you talking about doing this across the public Internet? (Please say no. Please.)

Comment: "Please say no. Please" Why is this such a trouble ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make it a recursive resolver.